# Python imports suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

In my current project I had the following structure:

```
- start.py (this script is run and imports from parentPackage and it's children) 
- parentPackage
   - subPackage1
     - __init__.py
     - foo.py
     - bar.py
     - ...
   - subPackage2
     - __init__.py
     - foo1.py
     - bar2
     - ...
   - __init__.py
   - someDataSource.py
   - someOtherThing.py
   - hereIsAnotherOne.py
   - andSomeMore.py
```

In the `__init__.py` files (underscores don't show on SO) I added the imports like this:

Example (parentPackage)

```
from .someDataSource.py import SomeDataSource
from .someOtherThing.py import SomeOtherThing
from .hereIsAnotherOne.py import HereIsAnotherOne
from .andSomeMore.py import AndSomeMore
```

I repeated this process for the subpackages aswell.

Then when I want to import SomeDataSource from the `.hereIsAnotherOne.py` I just write:

```
from parentPackage import SomeDataSource
```

This worked perfectly for a couple of weeks, but now suddenly stopped working.

I've tried to remove the `__init__.py` files from the subpackages and do those import in the `__init__.py` of the parentPackage, but that doesn't work.

How can this be? I have not touched the `__init__.py` files or anything, I only added a new file to the parentPackage.

Am I doing something wrong here? This always worked for me. I realise there are a lot of answers to this problem on SO, but none seem to be a fix for my problem.

*note*: I use PyCharm as my IDE, strange thing is PyCharm recognizes the imports as valid, no warnings nothing, until runtime.

Thank you all!

PS: I'm running python3.6

Comment: It is highly advisable to use absolute imports in Python: `from parent_package.sub_package.module import some_function`. Check also Python's PEP-8 for style.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular import:

In `parentPackage`, you import from `hereIsAnotherOne` **and**
in `hereIsAnotherOne`, you import from `parentPackage`. You have to resolve that by importing `SomeDataSource` straight from its source module `someDataSource.py` or importing it locally inside the function where you use it.

Either way, the occurrence of circular imports should make think long and hard about restructuring your current package architecture.

Comment: Hi there! So then `from .someDataSource.py import SomeDataSource` should work right? Sadly it does not. May these imports not be relative?